# How can I install source R packages from a local CRAN and binary for its dependencies?

Tags: r

I have a package which I wrote that is deployed on a local CRAN. I built the tgz with R CMD build and deployed it to a local cran initialised with miniCRAN. Of course, this package is deployed by miniCRAN as source.

Now, in a packrat environment I have to install this package and its dependencies, but the dependencies come from CRAN. I do

```
> install.packages("mypackage", repos=c("file:///path/to/my/localCRAN", "https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2018-08-01"), type="source")
```

However, this forces every package to build as source, and this fails because I don't have stuff to compile, say, dplyr or other stuff. I want to download the binaries for those.

If I issue instead

```
> install.packages("mypackage", repos=c("file:///path/to/my/localCRAN", "https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2018-08-01"))
```

then install.packages tries to install also my package as binary and stops first with this error

```
Error in read.dcf(file = tmpf) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In read.dcf(file = tmpf) :
  cannot open compressed file '/Users/username/my/localCRAN/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

So I created an empty PACKAGES file at that path, and now it fails with the following error

```
   package ‘mypackage’ is available as a source package but not as a binary

Warning message:
package ‘mypackage’ is not available (as a binary package for R version 3.5.3)
```

How can I install my package as source, and its CRAN dependencies as binary?